# Post tweets using tweepy and Twitter API V2

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I need my Twitter app to tweet some information, but something is going wrong.
First, I created an app and tried this code to test credentials:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET")
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_SECRET")
api = tweepy.API(auth)
try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication Successful")
except:
    print("Authentication Error")
```

And got "Authentication Error".
Then I tried to write a tweet directly using

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
client.create_tweet(text="********")
```

And now I got "tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden" What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to post a tweet via V2? here is the solution I just [answered to myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70062335/7339624)!

Install [tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org), then do as I do to tweet "Yeah boy! I did it".

```
!pip3 install tweepy --upgrade # to install and upgrade tweepy if you didn't.
```

Then make your BEARER, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, and ACCESS_SECRET ready. If you don't know how to find them you should check [Developer Platform](https://developer.twitter.com/) `-> Developer Portal -> Projects & Apps -> click on your project -> then look for "Keys and tokens"`

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER, consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY, consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, access_token=ACCESS_KEY, access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET)

client.create_tweet(text="Yeah boy! I did it")
```

This worked for me 100% tested. I still don't know if I can quote or reply to a tweet with V2 or not.

Comment: Sadly, this is no longer valid. `tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may 
need a different access level.`

Comment: Indeed. Even sold the furniture, I understand. The question now is if we close the question or delete the outdated answers.

Comment: I tried again. It works for me. Maybe it works for older APIs, I don't know. But this is the correct code for `tweepy` anyway.

Comment: To be fair, the code is correct, yes. I think the only way it could work for you is if you have a premium or academic account, though. Just for my own understanding and confirmation - is that the case? I would love to get this working again with my free account...

Comment: I don't remember, how can I check my account type? currently, in my "products" section is written `Twitter API v2`, as this question asked. P.S. Just below that page that I'm on, it is written "Free features: Manage Tweets,
Create and delete Tweets on behalf of a user."

Comment: it might have worked at one point, but now it does not work.  time to leave twitter...  any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to determine what exactly is happening in the first instance, since you're suppressing the actual error and printing that on any exception. You'll need to provide the full traceback for anyone to know what's going on with it.

However, if you have Essential access to the Twitter API, you won't be able to use Twitter API v1.1, and you'll encounter a 403 Forbidden error.
See the [FAQ section about that in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-403-forbidden-error-with-api) for more information.

For the latter error, make sure your app has the write permission.
See the [FAQ section about that in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error-with-api-or-403-forbidden-error-with-client) for more information.