# Twitter new API Essential access

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am a bit confused with the new Twitter API. According to [this page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/essential) any app in a project of a Developer account with Essential access can post tweets:

[image]

I have tried to do it both with Tweepy following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70062335/6571055) and using the sample code provided by Twitter [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Tweets/create_tweet.py), both unsuccessfully.

The Access Tokens that I can produce are Read-Only, which is why I guess nothing works. And indeed, when running the code, the prompt only asks to grant authorization for the app to read tweets, etc. nothing about posting. But at the same time I understand from the documentation that I should not need to do anything else (unlike some people say when they suggest to apply for Elevated access).
This is the error code I get when trying the sample code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Miguel\Documents\Proyectos\trolley_bot\create.py", line 65, in <module>
    raise Exception(
Exception: Request returned an error: 403 {"title":"Forbidden","detail":"Forbidden","type":"about:blank","status":403}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and I needed to add `oauth_callback` and `x_auth_access_type` to the `request_token` request:

https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Tweets/create_tweet.py#L16

```
request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write"
```

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/request_token

(credit to zmoon - https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/issues/73)

Comment: This is another approach I tried since I posted the question. In my case, it was no use, because after that I should authorize via PIN and it seems that Twitter has disabled that 3-leg auth. At least, it doesn't work the way most guides describe.

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe I had not activated Oauth v2 nor Oauth v1 and that's why it was failing.

Comment: @miguelsxvi - There was some discussion in the linked GitHub issue..sounds like Twitter has made some changes in this area recently. At the very least they're aware of the issues we're having. FYI