# Twitter V2 API POST /2/tweets 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweets

I am trying to make a bot, which posts tweets. 
Since my developer account is only essential, I am restricted to V2 API. At first, this is the example from github i used for posting a tweet: https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Tweets/create_tweet.py

```
consumer_key = "somekey"
consumer_secret = "somesecret"

payload = {"text": "Hello world!"}

request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)

try:
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
except ValueError:
    print(
    "There may have been an issue with the consumer_key or consumer_secret you entered."
    )
    
    
resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get("oauth_token")
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get("oauth_token_secret")
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % resource_owner_key)
print("Got OAuth token secret: %s" % resource_owner_secret)


# Get authorization
base_authorization_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print("Please go here and authorize: %s" % authorization_url)
verifier = input("Paste the PIN here: ")

# Get the access token
access_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
    resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
    verifier=verifier,
)
oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url)

access_token = oauth_tokens["oauth_token"]
access_token_secret = oauth_tokens["oauth_token_secret"]
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % access_token)
print("Got OAuth token: %s" % access_token_secret)


# Make the request
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)

# Making the request
response = oauth.post(
    "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets",
    json=payload,
)   

if response.status_code != 201:
    raise Exception(
        "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
    )

print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))

# Saving the response as JSON
json_response = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The user flow is the following. It seems OAuth has to be used, therefore, you have to get a 6 digit number and enter it in the terminal to get the access token:

```
Got OAuth token: #######
Got OAuth token secret: #######
Please go here and authorize: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=####
Paste the PIN here: ######
Got OAuth token: ########################################
Got OAuth token: ###############################
```

It's all working till the last step: actually posting the tweet with JSON. There, I get the following error:

```
Request returned an error: 403 {"title":"Forbidden","detail":"Forbidden","type":"about:blank","status":403}
```

What can I do? I simply want to post a tweet using Twitter V2 API, nothing more. Most tutorial use the old V1 or V1.1 api, which isn't helpful.

Edit: It seems to have to do something with the authentification being only read only: [Twitter new API Essential access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482492/twitter-new-api-essential-access)

Comment: As someone wrote here, the V2 permissions seem to be only read only. That's weird: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482492/twitter-new-api-essential-access

Comment: If you want to keep it simple I would use the Tweepy Python library

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue and I needed to add `oauth_callback` and `x_auth_access_type` to the `request_token` request:

https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Manage-Tweets/create_tweet.py#L16

```
request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&x_auth_access_type=write"
```

Source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/request_token

(credit to zmoon - https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/issues/73)